# Incomprehensible time format

Tags: python, datetime, python-2.7, datetime-format

I get from third-party service string with time. It looks like `PT8H30M`. What is the time format and how it convert into `datetime` object in Python 2.7

Comment: At a guess, ignoring the `P`, `T` stands for *Time*, `H` for hours, preceded by the hour count, and `M` stands for minutes, preceded by the minute count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume that the format gives only hours and minutes, you can use `datetime.datetime.strptime()` to parse these out, and return a `datetime.time` object from the result:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.strptime('PT8H30M', 'PT%HH%MM').time()
datetime.time(8, 30)
```